# How can I give to RoundCube the login credentials through HTTP so the user will not require to enter them?

Tags: email, php, auto-login, plesk, roundcube

Well, I have a dedicated hosting server service and it has a Plesk panel for its administration, as many will know Plesk comes with RoundCube as the default service for webmail access.

My issue is that the users of a created email account do not have direct control over the options of their account, that is, with the current configuration they cannot directly change their password from the webmail service or do other administrative activities on their account. However, if when creating an email account in Plesk I activate the "can be used to log in to Plesk" function, the user can use their email address and password as a user to enter on Plesk login to a limited panel of functions that allows them to do such activities I mentioned above, it even has the direct option on the panel of "Open Webmail" and these gets me to my question.

When you use this option, it sends you to the webmail service address with the following link "https://webmail.yourdomain.tld/roundcube/index.php?_user=usersaccount%40yourdomain.tld" and this takes you to the login page of RoundCube with the user field already filled with "usersaccount@yourdomain.tld".

Is there a way to also provide RoundCube with the password field as well?

I have tried adding the option "&_pass=userpass" to the end of the link but this does not work, like doing "https://webmail.yourdomain.tld/roundcube/index.php?_user=usersaccount%40yourdomain.tld&_pass=userpass".

My idea is to change the index.php file of the webmail subdomain by one developed that imitates the Plesk login but related to webmail access, that saves the credentials on a temporarily cookie and also modify the link of the "Open Webmail" option to include the password field so that the user can directly to their account, giving the end user a feeling of an integrated platform, something similar to what is currently done in cPanel. Since currently, as it is, the Plesk login is at an distant address from that webmail login part and there is no relationship from RoundCube with the Plesk address that could give the user any hint that they can manage their account without the need for intervention from the server administrator, therefore, as the platform is developed until now, the option for the end user to manage their account directly is almost as if it did not exist.

Comment: You should fix your title. HTTP != HTTPS. I imagine what you are trying is possible but is a really bad idea as if people bookmark the resulting link that bookmark contains their login details.

Comment: Looking briefly at my roundcube swtup from my mobile it populates quite a few hidden fields you might nred to reproduce - including _user and _pwd - I did not test what submitting these values done, but I would hope it would fail if the request is not a post type.  I would avoid it as a security nightmsre but I expect you can hack the roundcube signup form to populate the fields...

Comment: Well then, how does cPanel do it then?
Since what I'm proposing is to somewhat mimic on Plesk what they do on the webmail platform.

Answer (score 0):

**I URGE AGAINST DOING THIS.  IT IS VERY, VERY BAD FOR SECURITY**

I've done a bit of digging, and it is possible to modify the webmail form to inject a password into the password field.   I expect it might vary very slightly depending on version, but on Roundcube version 1.6 I could do this by editing on line 2345

/path/to/roundcube/program/include/rcmail_output_html.php

Search for $input_passwordfield and modify this so that it includes a 'value'=>$_REQUEST['_pass'] after the required => required field - ie change

```
input_pass   = new html_passwordfield(['name' => '_pass', 'id' => 'rcmloginpwd', 'required' => 'required']
        #    + $attrib + $pass_attrib);
```

to

```
    $input_pass   = new html_passwordfield(['name' => '_pass', 'id' => 'rcmloginpwd', 'required' => 'required','value'=>$_REQUEST['_pass']]
        + $attrib + $pass_attrib);
```

AGAIN - DON'T DO THIS.

I note that for a start this allows people to bookmark the URL with the password in it.  You may be able to mitigate this by using a $_POST and submitting it with a form.

I also have not bothered with any kind of sanity checking for the input.  No idea what effect this has.

Of-course, this all begs the question "why is the password stored in plain text in the first place that you can do this.

Comment: I'm using roundcube in combination with docker-mail-server to test incoming and outgoing e-mail for an application. I'm gonna integrate those links with direct login in my development README.md. With this solution it's really fast and convenient to switch between those accounts and view those mails. No security problem at all because these are not real accounts. Thank you!

Comment: @emcell Are you saying that the docker mail server can't send out emails?   Even if the accounts are not real accounts, if they can send email its a security risk - and even if not, storing unencrypted passwords - especially as part of links - is incredibly bad security posture.  Of-course you know your environment better then I do.